# No encuentro el error en este código

Tags: c

Tengo este código, yo quiero que la función "suma" (que quiero que sume la primera y última posición del arreglo) se aplique a un arreglo determinado. ¿Como hago para tomar la última posición del array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CUBO(a) a*a*a

int suma (int a[]);
int main()
{
 int size;
 printf("cant ar: ");
 scanf("%i",&size);
 int ar[size];
 for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
 {
    printf("valror %i: ",i+1);
    scanf("%i",&ar[i]);
 }
 printf("la suma es %i",suma(ar[]));
return 0;
}
int suma(a[]){
    int sum;
    sum= a[0] + CUBO(a[size-2]);
    return sum;
}
```

El compilador me indica que "size" no está declarada en la función, en python seria a[-1], pero como hago en C para que me indique la última posición del array?

Comment: Es `c#`, `c++` o `c`? Decídete

Comment: cuando llamas a una funcion solo tienes que mandarle el nombre de la variable, en tu caso estas mandando ´suma(ar[])´ eso es incorrecto, solo tienes que mandar ´suma(ar)´ y otro error que veo es que  en la implementacion del metodo Suma solo pones ´suma(a[])´ este es otro error, ya que la variable no tiene tipo, la manera correcta es ´suma(int a[])

Comment: **`c#`**, **`c++`** y **`c`** son distintos.

Comment: Por qué dices que hay un par de errores?

Comment: @LuisGarcia no era que el C te toma por defecto que el arreglo es tipo int? sino le indicas lo contrario

Comment: Otra de las cosas que el compilador me marca es que "size" no está declarada en la función, pero como hago para que me sume la última posición del array?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y indícanos esos detalles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> El compilador me indica que "size" no está declarada en la función

Efectivamente, si miramos la función `suma`:

```
int suma(int a[]){
    int sum;
    sum= a[0] + CUBO(a[size-2]);
    return sum;
}
```

Vemos que `size` no se encuentra definida en dicha función. `size` tampoco es una variable global, luego el error que te aparece es legítimo.

Fíjate que `size` sí que está declarada ... en la función `main`:

```
int main()
{
    int size;
}
```

Pero esta variable es propia de la función `main`.

Si necesitas usar `size` en `suma`, simplemente tienes que pasarla como parámetro:

```
int suma(int a[], int size){
    int sum;
    sum= a[0] + CUBO(a[size-2]);
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    printf("la suma es %i",suma(ar, size));
}
```

Un pequeño detalle adicional, fíjate que para pasar el array a `suma` simplemente hay que indicar el nombre de la variable `ar` **sin los corchetes**. Los corchetes solo hay que usarlos cuando deseamos acceder a una posición en concreto del array.

> ¿Como hago para tomar la última posición del array?

La última posición del array es `size - 1` y no `size - 2` como tienes en el código.

En cualquier caso el estándar solo entiende los arrays como elementos cuyo tamaño viene determinado en tiempo de compilación. Es decir, su tamaño debe ser una constante.

En tu caso esto no se cumple ya que `size` es una variable. Esto es lo que se conoce como VLA o Variable Length Array y su uso tiene varias implicaciones:

- Los arrays se crean en la pila del programa. Esta es una región con un tamaño bastante pequeño en comparación con la RAM. Si el usuario introduce un tamaño relativamente grande la pila podría desbordarse y con ello el programa moriría
- El estándar no permite los VLA. Si te compila es porque el compilador que estás usando te está ofreciendo soporte, pero el código podría no compilar usando un compilador diferente.
- No estás comprobando el valor de `size`. ¿Qué pasa si el usuario introduce 0 o un valor negativo?

Como reemplazo a los VLA te sugiero usar memoria dinámica:

```
int * ar = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

// ...

free(ar);
```

Comment: Al primer parámetro de la función le falta el tipo.

Comment: @Mateo cierto, no me di cuenta de ese error en la pregunta